# Xcode documentation links behave crazy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, documentation

The links in Xcode documentation, that mean the methods in the "Tasks" for example,
when i only put the mouse on the links, then the page go up.

What happen to Xcode?

Comment: When you mouse-over the links in the built-in Xcode documentation the page you are on scrolls to the top. Rather annoying...

Comment: Happens to me too, so I always just google for the class documentation.. I think I read it had to do with an issue in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this on and off as well in the previous version of Xcode.

I haven't seen the problem in Xcode 3.2.1.

This is a duplicate of question 1288900.

Answer (score 1):

It drives me crazy, too.

I found a simple work-around that hopefully works for you. Use the mouse and select some of the text on the page somewhere. That's it. For some reason, hovering over the links no longer makes the page snap to the top.